# Speeding Up MD5 Checks of Array of Files

Tags: android, performance, md5

I am looping through an array of files to see if any of the files in there match the last file in that array:

```
    List<File> files = Arrays.asList(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).listFiles());
    byte[] md5Downloaded = null;
    try {
        md5Downloaded = createChecksum(files.get(files.size()-1).getAbsolutePath());
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    for(File file : files){

        try {
            byte[] md5CurrentFile = createChecksum(file.getAbsolutePath());


            if(Arrays.equals(md5Downloaded, md5CurrentFile) && counter != files.size()-1 ){
                alertUserMD5(file, files.get(files.size()-1));
                return;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Here is the createChecksum method, which is borrowed:

```
private static byte[] createChecksum(String filename) throws Exception {
    InputStream fis =  new FileInputStream(filename);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    MessageDigest complete = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    int numRead;

    do {
        numRead = fis.read(buffer);
        if (numRead > 0) {
            complete.update(buffer, 0, numRead);
        }
    } while (numRead != -1);

    fis.close();
    return complete.digest();
}
```

However, I am not pleased with the amount of time this process takes (about 15 seconds). I realize that what I'm doing is highly dependent on the amount of files in the list, as well as the size of those files, but is there any way to speed this up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to figure out if a certain file is already available. If the files tend to be unrelated, you could compute the md5 of the first 1024 bytes only and compare with the last file. If it differs, no need to compare checksums of the whole files. Only if they turn out equal, you need to compare the md5 of the whole files.

Nearly forgot: compare file sizes even before, it may result in an early exit most of the time --- if the files are mostly unrelated.

Comment: Thanks. The sizes comparison suggestion helped me shave it down to about 4 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void searchFile() {
    long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
    List<File> files = new ArrayList<File>(Arrays.asList(dir.listFiles()));
    File downloaded = files.get(files.size() - 1);
    files.remove(files.size()-1);
    byte[] md5Downloaded = null;
    try {
        md5Downloaded = createChecksum(downloaded.getAbsolutePath());
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    Collections.sort(files, new Comparator<File>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(File lhs, File rhs) {
            return Long.valueOf(lhs.length()).compareTo(rhs.length());
        }
    });

    final byte[] MD5 = md5Downloaded;

    final int position = Collections.binarySearch(files, downloaded, new Comparator<File>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(File lhs, File rhs) {
            int compare =  Long.valueOf(lhs.length()).compareTo(rhs.length());
            if (compare == 0) {
                try {
                    if (Arrays.equals(MD5, createChecksum(lhs.getAbsolutePath()))) {
                        return 0;
                    }
                } catch (Exception ignored) {

                }
                return -1;
            } else
                return compare;
        }
    });

    if (position >= 0) {
        alertUserMD5(files.get(position), downloaded);
    }

}
```

Sorry for broken example, done it "in paper". Here is working example. Have tested it in directory with 578 files = 154 ms

Comment: I can't get this to give a non-negative number for position.